# Why is width in em wider than the same in px?

Tags: css, font-size

I supposed divs below to have the same width. But they are different, although `10px*10em` should be equal `100px`, similar like `10px*2em` equals `20px`.

```css
#container1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#paragraph1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#container2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#paragraph2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container1'>
  <p id='paragraph1'>abc</p>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
  <p id='paragraph2'>abc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A great article about this question: [http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px](http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my real problem, but I found answer during writing this question. Reason is simple: `em` units using for `width` of element are relative to `font-size` of their own element, not the parent's. So, as `font-size` equals `2em`, which equals `20px`, everything is right, because `20px*10em` equals `200px`.

When I change `width` to `5em`, it works as it should:

```css
#container1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#paragraph1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#container2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#paragraph2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container1'>
  <p id='paragraph1'>abc</p>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
  <p id='paragraph2'>abc</p>
</div>
```